# Awtan method in caret::train fails with Error: lpawnb is not an exported objects from namespace:bnclassify

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm trying to create a predictive model using the `awtan` method in `caret`, but training continues to fail with the error:

```
 model fit failed for Resample04: score=bic, smooth=1 Error : 'lpawnb' is not an exported object from 'namespace:bnclassify'
```

I'm using bnclassify version 0.3.4. Based on the release notes on github, it looks like `lpawnb()` was replaced by `lp()` in version 0.3.2, so my initial guess is that the problem is some sort of legacy bug (in caret? in bnclassify?) that's calling the latter instead of the former.

On the other hand, perhaps I'm just doing something wrong. Here's a toy example:

```
library(caret)
librarY

data  <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var5 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var6 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), var8 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0",  "1"), class = "factor"), outcome = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1",  "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "outcome" ), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")  

model  <- train(x = data %>% select(-outcome), y = data$outcome, method = 'awtan')
# Eventually dies with the following errors
#
# Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
#     Accuracy       Kappa    
#  Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
#  1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
#  Median : NA   Median : NA  
#  Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
#  3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
#  Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
#  NA's   :6     NA's   :6    
# Error: Stopping
# In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
# 
# 
# > warnings()
# Warning messages:
# 1: model fit failed for Resample01: score=loglik, smooth=1 Error : 'lpawnb' is not an exported object from 'namespace:bnclassify'
# 
# 2: model fit failed for Resample01: score=bic, smooth=1 Error : 'lpawnb' is not an exported object from 'namespace:bnclassify'
# 
# 3: model fit failed for Resample01: score=aic, smooth=1 Error : 'lpawnb' is not an exported object from 'namespace:bnclassify'
```

Using the same data, I'm able to build a model using `bnclassify`'s functions, so I'm guessing it's a bug in `caret`, calling `lpawnb()` when the appropriate functions is `bnclassify::lp()`, but again, I'm unclear as to how to confirm this.

Can anyone shed any light on what I might be doing wrong (before I blame package developers much smarted than I am)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the current version of caret on CRAN, 6.0-78, defines the fit function for awtan models using `bnclassify::lpawnb()`, while bnclassify has replaced it with `lp()`:

```
getModelInfo('awtan')

... 
    $awtan$fit
function (x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) 
{
    dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x
    else as.data.frame(x)
    dat$.outcome <- y
    struct <- bnclassify::tan_cl(class = ".outcome", dataset = dat, 
        score = as.character(param$score))
    bnclassify::lpawnb(struct, dat, smooth = param$smooth, trees = 10, 
        bootstrap_size = 0.5, ...)
}
...
```